# Dictionary weird behavior when adding item in Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I find an interesting thing that when I tried to add an item into a dictionary in the Parallel loop. It throws a `NullReferenceException` exception. I can fixed it, but I don't know why it throw that exception. I was wondering if someone can help me clear on that. Below is the source code, it's very simple.

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<int, Projection> CachedProjections =
        new Dictionary<int, Projection>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var key = 3857;
        Parallel.For(0, 400, _ => 
        {
            Projection projection = null; // If remove the null initialization it works well.
            if (CachedProjections.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                projection = CachedProjections[key];
            }
            else
            {
                projection = new Projection();
                CachedProjections[key] = projection;
            }
        });

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Projection
{
    public Projection()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10); // If comment out this line, it works well too.
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) if you want to use your dictionary with multiple threads.

Comment: try it as a non static methode

Comment: @FelixQuehl that should be related at all

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary is not thread safe against writes + (anything else). That means you'd need to lock around all the dictionary operations, which probably obviates all the things that you're trying to achieve. You *could* also look at concurrent-dictionary, but don't assume that it will be faster - it is... complicated and depends on whether you have competing read+read, read+write, write+write, etc.

Comment: A  [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) is faster than using a lock around all operations and is pretty easy to use.

Comment: @Rango that is a hugely simplistic statement; it *really* depends on what the competing operations are

Comment: I just referred to your simplistic statement _"but don't assume that it will be faster - it is... complicated "_ A `ConcurrentDictionary` uses separate locks for each hash bucket so should outperform a normal dictionary which needs a total-lock for all operations. At least if you use it like OP (`ContainsKey` + indexer)

Answer (score 0):

Because [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) is not thread-safe:

> A Dictionary can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration. To allow the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

For thread-safe alternatives, see the [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<K, V>` is not thread safe. Use [Thread-Safe Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) for multithreading applications. In your case use the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue> Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2).

See also: [How to: Add and Remove Items from a ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-add-and-remove-items)